# Same statement gives an error inside for loop

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, flask, jinja2

The Server side uses python with flask, and the html template is jinja2. I'm trying to make a marker with google api. The latitude and longitude information are stored in `stores[][]` which is passed from python. This code is between `<script>` tag in my html file and it works fine.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: {{stores[0][5]}}, lng: {{stores[0][6]}}}, map: map});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: {{stores[4][5]}}, lng: {{stores[4][6]}}}, map: map});
```

I have multiple lat,lng from which I want to make markers, so I put it inside a `for` loop.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: {{stores[i][5]}}, lng: {{stores[i][6]}}}, map: map});
}
```

Exactly same code, but the index is `i` was put instead of a number for indexing. It suddenly gives errors saying

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element Undefined
```

I double checked that `stores[][]` have more than 5 elements. This is very very confusing.

Comment: Best guess is `stores` is populated from asynchronous operation and you are running the loop before it is populated. Show source of `stores`. See [mcve]

Comment: I'd try console.table(stores[i]) inside the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. Jinja is evaluated entirely on the server, well before the JS can run on the client. There is no way for Jinja to have access to variables from the JS code.

You should move the loop to Jinja itself.

```
{% for store in stores %}
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: {{ store[5] }}, lng: {{ store[6] }}}, map: map});
{% endfor %}
```